# Two servers, same domain name, can't get cookies

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, cookies, cors

Title says it all, I'm having trouble figuring out why I'm unable to get or set cookies from two different servers on the same domain. With `$path` set to `/`, `$domain` specified as `127.0.0.1`, `$secure` set `false`, and `$httponly` set `false`.

Here's the situation in more detail:

**Server 1 - 127.0.0.1**

> On `Server 1` I have a PHP script that gets a cookie if it's set, and sets a new cookie. Then the old and new cookie values are returned as JSON.

**Server 2 - 127.0.0.1:8000**

> On `Server 2` with the same domain name but a different port, I have an HTML file that requests the script from `Server 1`. I cannot get the cookie, or set a new one from `Server 2`.

Here are the files:

**PHP script on `Server 1`**

```
<?php

header ('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

$old = !empty ($_COOKIE['test']) ? $_COOKIE['test'] : 'none';
$new = rand (0, 1000);

setcookie ('test', $new, time () * 2, '/', '127.0.0.1', false, false);

echo json_encode ('old: ' . $old . ' new: '. $new);
```

**HTML file on `Server 2`**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var test = new XMLHttpRequest ();

            test.onreadystatechange = function ()
            {
                if (this.readyState !== 4 || this.status !== 200) {
                    return;
                }

                document.body.innerHTML = JSON.parse (this.responseText);
            };

            test.open ('POST', 'http://127.0.0.1/cookieget.php', true);
            test.send ();
        </script>
    </head>

    <body></body>
</html>
```

"What the heck is going on?!"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the two servers have the same hostname, they have different ports, so they’re different origins. And browsers will not let you set cookies cross-origin.

Two origins are considered the same only if they have the same scheme, hostname, and port.

Comment: Even though the script doing the cookie setting is always on the same domain and port, just accessed from elsewhere?

Comment: As far as origin restrictions goes, what happens on the server side doesn’t matter, because browsers do not see that. For origin restrictions the only thing relevant is what happens on the frontend client side. So you if have a Web application at origin A that sets cookies, a Web application at origin B cannot access those cookies—even if source for the two Web applications is hosted on exactly the same server on the backend.